# Why browser takes 2 minutes to compile single html page (5000 lines) in angular 2 application? is any limitation for html content in single page?

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-template, ng2-bootstrap

- i have started with angular CLI quick start. and imported
  [ng2-boostrap](http://[ng2-bootstrap][1]%20%20%20%20%20[1]:%20https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/accordion) accordion module in app.module.ts file.
- added **html code of 5000 lines with number of accordion** in
  app.component.html file

Desing page: accordion with pdf links and contain expand collapse image looks like below

[image: design of accordion with pdf links and images]

like below:

```
<div class="inner-accordion">
<accordion>
    <accordion-group #cross>
        <div accordion-heading>
            CLAIM FORMS
            <span>
                <img src="images/down_arrow.png" *ngIf="!cross.isOpen" />
                <img src="images/up_arrow.png" *ngIf="cross.isOpen" />
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <p>
               <a href="/src/assets/files/forms/claims/ClaimForm.pdf" target="_blank">Claim Form</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

**Problem 1:**

when i trying to access page from browser it takes 2 minutes to display page and also got page unresponsive popup with kill or wait.
**is any possibilities to reduce the page loading time**.

**Problem 2:**

when i trying to get those html file from separate html template using $.ajax call and assign it to innerHTML of div then accordion expand collapse is not working.

Suggest me what are the best solutions to reduce the page loading time?

Comment: 1.) Why is everything in 1 page? Are they already modularized? Chances are, they are not. E.g. broken into reusable components. Angular is great for breaking reusable components and loading them using lazy load. i.e. load if only needed.    
2.) Are you sure that loading the page is the problem? Check Network and verify that the download is the problem. If it isn't, check if rendering is the problem using chrome timeline. if it isn't, check if there are any long loops using profiler.

Comment: Thanks for your comment JaredT :                                                   
       1.)Why is everything in 1 page:  whole content is related to one thing. and easily editing purpose i have kept into single file. and also i tried with modularized then the problem occures at the time of click the router link will takes much time to render page.

Comment: Basically you have chosen to do preloading, where your application loads everything in 1 go. Hence the long wait time.
This is the consequence of your decision, there is no going around it.
Preloading is usually done if the application is really small.
If you have done it lazy loading, then sure every click needs to call server to fetch next page, but would be a better user experience over all.

How could 5k lines all be related to 1 thing? They are relevant to each other, sure, but not dependent! Even a submenu can be broken down to X number of components.

Editing purpose.. what?

Comment: IMO 5k lines of HTML shouldn't really take 3min in 2017. Sounds like you have bombarded your page with images or something.

Comment: yes i have number of pdf links and images present in my page.

Answer (score 0):

JIT mode compilation is intended to be used only during development, for production you should use AOT:

`ng build --prod --aot`

Comment: yes, for production i have used AOT is working fine, but i need it for development also.

Comment: `ng serve --aot` is possible, but you will get slower build times, so you should choose which one is faster...

Answer (score 0):

The page is too huge to load in browser! 
Try to use paging or lazy loading content when scrolling (e.g https://github.com/orizens/ngx-infinite-scroll)